# Reflux - Multiples actions in the same view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, refluxjs

I'm pretty new using `reactjs` & `reflux` and I have no idea how to implement the next situation:

I have a view with some tabs, each tab is going to have different data coming from an API. So far what I have done is the code below:

My Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Reflux from 'reflux';
import SocialStore from '../stores/socialStore';
import Card from './shared/card.js'


var Social = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(SocialStore, 'socialstore')],

  render: function() {
    if(this.state.socialstore){
      var tempSocialStore = this.state.socialstore
    }else{
      var tempSocialStore = [];
    }

    return <div className="android-be-together-section">
        <div className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
          <header className="mdl-layout__header">
            <div className="mdl-layout__header-row">
              <span className="mdl-layout-title">Portfolio</span>
            </div>
            <div className="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
              <a href="#scroll-tab-1" className="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Stackoverflow</a>
              <a href="#scroll-tab-2" className="mdl-layout__tab">GitHub</a>
              <a href="#scroll-tab-3" className="mdl-layout__tab">Twitter</a>
              <a href="#scroll-tab-4" className="mdl-layout__tab">Instagram</a>
            </div>
          </header>
          <main className="mdl-layout__content">
            <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
              <div className="page-content">
                <div className="content">
                  {
                    tempSocialStore.map(function (item){
                      return  <Card title={item.title_description} description={item.summary_description} btnTitle="View" link={item.id_description} />
                    })
                  }
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
              <div className="page-content">content 2</div>
            </section>
            <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-3">
              <div className="page-content">content 3</div>
            </section>
            <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-4">
              <div className="page-content">content 4</div>
            </section>
          </main>
        </div>
    </div>
  }
});

export default Social;
```

Actions:

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';

let SocialActions = Reflux.createActions([
  'getStackoverflowFeed',
  'getTwitter',
  'getGithub',
  'getInstagram'
]);

export default SocialActions;
```

Store:

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';
import $ from 'jquery';
import SocialActions from '../actions/SocialActions';

var SocialStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [SocialActions],
  stackoverflowList: [],
  twitterList: [],
  instagramList: [],
  githubList: [],
  sourceUrlStackoverflow: 'url-1',
  sourceUrlTwitter: 'url-2',
  sourceUrlInstagram: 'url-3',
  sourceUrlGithub: 'url-4',

  init: function(){
      this.getStackoverflowFeed(); //First Tab
  },

  getTwitter: function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: this.sourceUrlTwitter,
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          context: this,
          success: function(data) {
            this.twitterList = data.results;
            this.trigger(this.twitterList);
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log('There was an error while your request');
          }
      });
  },

  getInstagram: function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: this.sourceUrlInstagram,
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          context: this,
          success: function(data) {
            this.instagramList = data.results;
            this.trigger(this.instagramList);
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log('There was an error while your request');
          }
      });
  },

  getGithub: function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: this.sourceUrlGithub,
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          context: this,
          success: function(data) {
            this.githubList = data.results;
            this.trigger(this.githubList);
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log('There was an error while your request');
          }
      });
  },

  getStackoverflowFeed: function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: this.sourceUrlStackoverflow,
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          context: this,
          success: function(data) {
            this.stackoverflowList = data.results; //TODO: Remove comments from the list.
            this.trigger(this.stackoverflowList);
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log('There was an error while your request');
          }
      });
  }
});

export default SocialStore;
```

So the first time yo enter is working the first tab because I have instantiated it in the `init`, but I don´t know how to set the `state` in each tab when the user click in them and fill the content.

any idea how to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people who have the same question. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do here to better leverage the reflux pattern:

- The `SocialStore` should be responsible for storing the `state` of which tab is currently selected, and the `Social` component should be rendering with respect to that `state`.
- You should have an event listener for each time a tab is selected or selection changed, i.e. `onSelectionChange`. `onSelectionChange` should fire off and call the corresponding `Action`, which the `SocialStore` will listen to and changes the `state` of which tab is currently selected.
- Your `Social` component then listens to `SocialStore` change and updates its component state, which `render()` is triggered again and your view properly reflects what is selected
- By looking at how similar each social `Action` and `Store` are and how they're implemented. I highly suggest you factor out all your `Actions` into a single one but takes in a parameter indicating which tab is selected. The same goes to factoring out the handling of `get{Social}` function in the `Store`. (This step is optional but results in cleaner and more maintainable code)